# Nodejs Multer how to send images in array with variable in postman

Tags: node.js, express, postman

I have simple api in which I need to pass images with some variable like imageType etc.

My Nodejs code

```
const FILE_TYPE_MAP_image = {
    'image/png': 'png',
    'image/jpeg': 'jpeg',
    'image/jpg': 'jpg'
};

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        const isValid = new Error('invalid image type');
        if (isValid) {
            uploadError = null;
        }
        cb(uploadError, 'public/uploads');
    },

    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        const fileName = file.originalname.split(' ').join('-');
        const extension = FILE_TYPE_MAP_image[file.mimetype];
        cb(null, `${fileName}-${Date.now()}.${extension}`);
    }
})
const uploadOptions = multer({ storage: storage });


const createalbum = async (req, res) => {

    const listofdata = [];
    const basePath = `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/public/uploads/`;

    console.log(req)
    req.body.images.forEach(element => {
        listofdata.push({
            url: `${basePath}${element.url.filename}`,
            uploadType: element.uploadType,
        })
    });
    console.log(listofdata)

}


module.exports = {
    createalbum: [uploadOptions.array('images', 10), createalbum]
};
```

In postman I am sending like this and it's showing unexpected fields. I try with images also like images[0][url] but it's also not working and its keep showing unexpected value. I am not able to find how ill send it through postman with an variable like in same array file and imageType.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of uploads[0][url] please set KEY images and add multiple images by CTRL key and select images.
[image]
I take a screenshot from my postman and attached it to this post and a sample code was added there:
Please pay attention to the comments on the sample code.

```
app.post('/photos/upload', upload.array('photos', 12), function (req, 
  res, next) {
      // req.files is array of `photos` files
     // req.body will contain the text fields, if there were any
  })
```